# How to fix colcon build fail?

Tags: ros, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/ for ROS 2.0 Eloquent on Mac OS Catalina. This fails after entering the `colcon build --symlink-install` command and I get this error message:

```
user@users-MBP ros2_example_ws % sudo colcon build --symlink-install
Password:
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  /Users/user/Desktop/ros2_example_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


---
Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server  [ Exited with code 1 ]
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  /Users/user/Desktop/ros2_example_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


---
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  /Users/user/Desktop/ros2_example_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


---
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
--- stderr: examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ament_package.templates import get_environment_hook_template_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'
CMake Error at /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_package_templates-extras.cmake:41 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3
  /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/package_templates/templates_2_cmake.py
  

    /Users/user/Desktop/ros2_example_ws/build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_client/ament_cmake_package_templates/templates.cmake)
      returned error code 1
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/ament_cmake_coreConfig.cmake:38 (include)
      /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:15 (find_package)
      /Users/user/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmakeConfig.cmake:38 (include)
      CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)
    
    
    ---
    Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
    
    Summary: 0 packages finished [0.81s]
      1 package failed: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
      3 packages aborted: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
      4 packages had stderr output: examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
      12 packages not processed
```

A reoccurring bit of this log is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ament_package'`, which I tried to investigate. It seems that ament_package does exist but somehow things aren't quite linked up as expected to get things working.

Does anybody have any ideas how I might solve this?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339188/how-to-fix-colcon-build-fail?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After looking at this again I have found that I needed to add `source ~/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/setup.bash` to the `.bashrc` file. This was explained in the instruction at https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/OSX-Install-Binary/ but I've misunderstood something and thought I needed to use the `.zshrc` rather than `.bashrc` on OSX Catalina, which has proved not to be the case.

Thanks for helping to solve this!

---

Originally posted by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) with karma: 501 on 2019-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2019-12-11**:
glad you found the correct fix!
You should be able to mark your own answer as correct (so that this issue can be considered closed)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May not qualify as an answer but these errors usually happen when the environment is not set up properly.

Did you follow the previous steps of the tutorial? Especially the ["Source an underlay" section](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/#source-an-underlay), if you install  eloquent from binaries it should look similar to https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/OSX-Install-Binary/#environment-setup

Also it is surprising that you have to run `colcon` with `sudo`. Does it fail differently if you build without `sudo`?

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2019-12-06**:
Thanks for the reply! I believe I followed the "Source an underlay" section, but it is possible that I've made a mistake. Here's the contents of my .zshrc file:

```
export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl
export OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
source ~/ros2_eloquent/ros2-osx/setup.zsh
```

Does this look like it's got any obvious errors in it? I run `colcon` with `sudo` because it just gives me a `permission denied` error otherwise. Do you think this gives any clues?